# My Request does not work in HTTPClient and RestSharp but well in Postman

Tags: c#, rest, http, oauth-2.0, httpclient

I'm on Xamarin and would like to execute an HTML request to collect a token from a server I manage. 
I can successfully execute the following Request on PostMan.
[image: Postman request]
But once I try to code it it does not work. 
I tried two different ways. 
Firstly by using HTTPClient the following way:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = AppConfiguration.CloudServer_URI + "/token";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // define the expected return format

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/token");
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "admin@example.com"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "Admin@123465")
        });

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

This gives me well a response but with 400 - Bad request. 
I cannot find in the HTTPResponse where I can get the details on the response body. But I strongly guest it is an "error": "unsupported_grant_type".

Then I tried another way with RestSharp and got the following implementation:

```
        string URL = AppConfiguration.CloudServer_URI + "/token";
        var client = new RestClient(URL);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.AddParameter("username", "admin@example.com", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.AddParameter("password", "Admin@123465", ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

But again the result is the same - 400 - Bad request. And here I can see the response body which is "error": "unsupported_grant_type".

I have the feeling to miss something obvious but I don't see what.

Comment: The only difference I see is that you are using Post in Postman and using Method.Get in your request via code. Also (and likely not an issue) is that your are using Token with a capital T in Postman, but using a lowercase t in the code.

Comment: Yes I did a wrong screenshot of PostMan. Because I tested so many configurations. But both Post and Get provide the same result... I also tried with and without the capital with the same unfortunate result.

Comment: Can the httpS have an impact. Should the SSL been explicitly declared?

Comment: So I could finally solve part of the job. The password was inconsistently been copied in both code!. Nevertheless the only first code is working. The second one still have the same behavior...